# Powershell convertfrom-string automatically parses decimal to dates. How do I prevent this?

Tags: string, powershell, string-parsing

Im trying to convert data from cli to powershell object using ConvertFrom-String, however when I do that decimal numbers are automatically parsed as dates (As seen in column P4 below). How do I prevent this ?

`plesk bin php_handler --list | ConvertFrom-String  | select P2,P4,P11 | where{$_.P11 -like 'enabled'}`

```
P2          P4                   P11    
--          --                   ---    
fastcgi-5   5/2/2017 12:00:00 AM enabled
fastcgi-5.3 5/3/2029 12:00:00 AM enabled
fastcgi-5.4 5/4/1945 12:00:00 AM enabled
fastcgi-5.5 5/5/1938 12:00:00 AM enabled
fastcgi-5.6 5/6/1940 12:00:00 AM enabled
fastcgi-7.0 7.0.33               enabled
fastcgi-7.1 7/1/1930 12:00:00 AM enabled
isapi-5     5/2/2017 12:00:00 AM enabled
```

Comment: It's hard to be specific without knowing what the input looks like, but you can use a template with annotations to specify what data type each property is:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string

Answer (score 1):

You will either need to use a template or manipulate the property using a calculated property if you are going to use `ConvertFrom-String`:

**Using Calculated Property:**

```
plesk bin php_handler --list | ConvertFrom-String |
    Select-Object P2,@{n='P4';e={if ($_.P4 -is [datetime]) { $_.P4.ToString('M.d.yyyy')} else {$_.P4}}},P11 |
        Where P11 -eq 'enabled'
```

---

You can take a different approach and use `Foreach-Object` with custom properties instead:

```
plesk bin php_handler --list | Where {$data = -split $_; $data[10] -eq 'enabled'} |
    Foreach-Object { [pscustomobject]@{P1=$data[0];P4=$data[3];P11=$data[10]} }
```

---

You could make your own function, which would give you nearly limitless customization:

```
function ConvertTo-MyObject {
    param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$InputObject)
    process {
        $i = 1
        $hash = [ordered]@{}
        -split $input | Foreach-Object { $hash[$("P"+$i++)] = $_ }
        [pscustomobject]$hash
    }
}

plesk bin php_handler --list | ConvertTo-MyObject |
    Where P11 -eq 'enabled' | Select P2,P4,P11
```