# ConvertFrom-String that contains decimal numbers

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I am trying to convert a string containing mixed data into a table. So far, I have the following:

```
    [string]$aStringWithNumbers = 'Process started. 
    Process completed with no errors.
    Time to complete = 4.249 = 100% CPU time = 43.859' 
    
    ConvertFrom-String $aStringWithNumbers
```

Which gives the following output:

```
P1  : Process
P2  : started.
P3  : Process
P4  : completed
P5  : with
P6  : no
P7  : errors.
P8  : Time
P9  : to
P10 : complete
P11 : =
P12 : 4
P13 : =
P14 : 100%
P15 : GPU
P16 : time
P17 : =
P18 : 44
```

While this brings my data into a format I can handle, `ConvertFrom-String` seems to be rounding any decimal data into integer format. What can I do to extract the decimal numbers intact?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63937049/powershell-convertfrom-string-automatically-parses-decimal-to-dates-how-do-i-pr

Comment: Okay, so instead of using ``` ConvertFrom-String ``` I should instead create and run the ``` ConvertTo-MyObject ``` function used in the answer. That appears to do the trick for me, with some minor adjustments. ($input needs to be changed to $InputObject for the example function to work properly)

Comment: You can still use `$input` for a basic pipeline `function`  but I believe linked answer solves your problem. If so we can close this one as a duplicate

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Very well. Should I simply delete the question? (First time posting a question)

Comment: That's ok no need to delete it. Tho if the linked duplicate doesn't fully answer your question @ me again